# Product list alignment disturbed after plugin update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have updated the woocommerce plugin to 2.6.1 version. After the update the number of product items per row in store listing is not working properly. 
For example if I have 6 products totally in my woocommerce store, the number of products per row are displayed as below:

```
Row 1 ---> 1 Product

Row 2 ---> 2 Products

Row 3 ---> 1 Product

Row 4 ---> 2 Products
```

Have anyone faced his issue with woocommerce store listing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the issue persist while using the Twenty Sixteen theme? If not, the problem is in your theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a link that can show us exactly what it looks like, it would be easier to diagnose.

It's probably the width and margin of the page. This can happen if the widths/margins are set in percentages which add up to more than 100% or if they're set in pixels that add up to more than the width of your browser. If it's trying to make a row of 3 every time, so it's working like this:

```
Row 1 = Items 1-3

Row 2 = Items 4-6

**Correct:**
________________
Item 1 -- Item 2 -- Item 3
________________
Item 4 -- Item 5 -- Item 6
________________

**Currently:**
________________
Item 1 -- Item 2 --

Item 3
________________
Item 4 -- Item 5 --

Item 6
________________
```